# How do I get the correct value of offsetWidth after the fonts have loaded in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, dom

I'm calling offsetWidth for a component I have in my React project.

However because I'm loading fonts via @font-face through an index.css file, it seems the offsetWidth I get is wrong, because my custom font is then loaded and changes the width of my element which happens to be a Table.

How do I wait for the font to be loaded and applied to my text before calling offsetWidth in React?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got around this by just executing my code in the load event listener for window.

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  ...code here...
}
```